# Total count of files,folders and sub folders in the current directory using batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have the directory structure like this A->B->C,D->E,F Where A contains B folder and some  text files,sql files,log files etc. B contains C folder and many other extension files.
Similarly E,F are also sub-directories and contains some files.
Now the output should be something like this:
Count of files:
A-10
A/B-15
A/B/C-20
D-25
D/E-30
F-12
Thanks for your response.All approaches are appreciated.

Have tried:

```
@ECHO OFF 
SET "rootpath=%~1" 
FOR /D %%D IN ("%~dp0*") DO ( 
    SET cnt=0 
    FOR /F %%K IN ('DIR /A-D /S "%%D" 2^>NUL ^| FIND "File(s)" ^|^| ECHO 0') DO ( SET /A cnt+=%%K ) 
    SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion 
    ECHO %%D: !cnt! 
    ENDLOCAL 
    pause
)
```

Comment: What do you got so far? What have you tried?

Comment: I tried the below code but its pulling wrong results and giving only the immediate folders but not the count of files in sub-directories.
@ECHO OFF
SET "rootpath=%~1"
FOR /D %%D IN ("%~dp0\*") DO (
  SET cnt=0
  FOR  /F %%K IN ('DIR /A-D /S "%%D" 2^>NUL ^| FIND "File(s)" ^|^| ECHO 0') DO (
    SET /A cnt+=%%K
  )
  SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
  ECHO %%D: !cnt!
  ENDLOCAL
  pause
)
Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Your description and question title are unclear; so you want to get the count of _files_ (not dir.s) per (sub-)directory in the full tree in the current directory? does the tree root contain files to be counted too? is `F` a dir. on top-level or is it a sub-dir. of `E`? does the output need to show relative paths to the (sub-)directories? And what is the problem with your code?

Comment: I want ot get the count of files in directories,sub-directories and sub-sub directories.So I want the count if F and E also.The problem with my code was that it was pulling the results(count of files) for immediate folders where I triggered the .bat file and its not pulling the count of files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a *recursive subroutine* that traverse the entire tree and perform the same calculation in each subfolder. This approach is simpler:

**EDIT**: Code modified to avoid errors when subfolder names have spaces.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "base=%cd%\"

rem Accumulate files in the same array element given by its folder
for /R %%a in (*.*) do (
   set "folder=%%~DPa"
   set "folder=!folder:%base%=!"
   set /A "count[!folder: =_!]+=1" 2> nul
)

rem Show the result
for /F "tokens=2,3 delims=[]=" %%a in ('set count[') do (
   echo %%a-%%b
)
```

For further description of array management in Batch files, see: [Arrays, linked lists and other data structures in cmd.exe (batch) script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990)

Comment: Could you please tell me how to output the path and no of files: A-10 A/B-20 something like this..please don't feel bad I am not good at batch script. Thanks for your quick reponse

Comment: While I m running this bat I could able to see some error 'missing operand' will this be causing an issue.please help

Comment: The problem was caused by folder names that included spaces. I modified the code to replace spaces by underscores. If you wish, the spaces may be recovered before the result is displayed...

Comment: I am very grateful to you...Thanks a lot!!